# How to add minutes to a column

Tags: r

I need to match up three sources of data with differing times. I have tried to add 55 minutes to a column using hms and timechange without success.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(timechange)
library(hms)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                  time = as.hms(c('18:12:55', '18:12:57', '18:12:59')))
                 
df1 %>%
  mutate(time.f = time_add(time, minutes = "00:55:00"))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time.f`.
#> x Unsupported date-time class 'hms'Unsupported date-time class 'difftime'
#> i Input `time.f` is `time_add(time, minutes = "00:55:00")`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time_add` function only supports objects of class  `datetime`. The class of time column from the dataframe is `hms` and `difftime`, hence the error stating that 'hms' and 'difftime' are unsupported.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(timechange)
library(hms)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                  time = as_hms(c('18:12:55', '18:12:57', '18:12:59')))

class(df1$time)
[1] "hms"      "difftime"
```

Therefore, just convert the 55 minutes to an `hms` object with `as_hms`, add it to the `time` column then convert the result to an `hms` object.

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(time.f = as_hms(time + as_hms('00:55:00')))

  ID     time   time.f
1  1 18:12:55 19:07:55
2  2 18:12:57 19:07:57
3  3 18:12:59 19:07:59
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the `timechange` package. Also, `as.hms` is deprecated.

Below find my solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                  time = as_hms(c('18:12:55', '18:12:57', '18:12:59')))
                 
df1 %>%
  mutate(time.f = as_hms(time + as_hms("00:55:00")))
>  ID     time   time.f
> 1  1 18:12:55 19:07:55
> 2  2 18:12:57 19:07:57
> 3  3 18:12:59 19:07:59
```

In case you really need to use the `timechange` package, you have to convert the `time` variable from the `hms` class to `POSIXct` class. Find the code for this second option below.

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(time.f = as_hms(time_add(as.POSIXct(time), minutes = 55)))
>   ID     time   time.f
> 1  1 18:12:55 19:07:55
> 2  2 18:12:57 19:07:57
> 3  3 18:12:59 19:07:59
```

Answer (score 1):

`time_add` won't work with `hms` objects.
Try this:

```r
df1 %>% 
   mutate(time.f = as_hms(time + hms(minutes=50)))
```

One additional, unrelated thing is to probably be careful with loading both the `lubridate` and `hms` package in the same environment, since they have `hms` in common. And since most people bounce around both, it often helps to prefix your `hms` functions as `hms::`.